Expo returns "Metro error: Unable to resolve module react-dom/server.node" error?
I have a new React Native Expo app that I've been developing, and I noticed recently that when opening a drawer or modal, I get the following error in my terminal:
λ Bundling failed 71ms node_modules/expo-router/node/render.js (1 module)

Metro error: Unable to resolve module react-dom/server.node from /Users/<me>/Documents/repositories/<project>/node_modules/expo-router/build/static/renderStaticContent.js: react-dom/server.node could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules/expo-router/node_modules
  node_modules
  38 | const Font = __importStar(require("expo-font/build/server"));
  39 | const react_1 = __importDefault(require("react"));
> 40 | const server_node_1 = __importDefault(require("react-dom/server.node"));
     |                                                ^
  41 | const react_native_web_1 = require("react-native-web");
  42 | const getRootComponent_1 = require("./getRootComponent");
  43 | const _ctx_1 = require("../../_ctx");


Call Stack
  <unknown> (node_modules/expo-router/build/static/renderStaticContent.js:0)
Web Bundling failed 3819ms node_modules/expo-router/entry.js (2427 modules)

My package.json as such:
{
  "name": "test_mobile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx expo start",
    "android": "npx expo run:android",
    "ios": "npx expo run:ios",
    "web": "npx expo start --web",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "typegen": "npx supabase gen types typescript --local public > ./types/index.ts && tsx scripts/generateEnums.ts",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cloudinary/url-gen": "^1.20.0",
    "@dev-plugins/react-query": "^0.0.7",
    "@expo/html-elements": "0.4.2",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "5.0.0-alpha.10",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.9.0",
    "@legendapp/motion": "^2.4.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.7.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.37.2",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.45.2",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.55.4",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.13",
    "expo": "^51.0.31",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~6.4.2",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.5",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.26",
    "expo-image": "~1.12.15",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.23",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "lucide-react-native": "^0.436.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.53.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-click-outside": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "sonner-native": "^0.8.0",
    "stripe": "^16.10.0",
    "supabase": "^1.192.5",
    "zod": "^3.23.8",
    "zustand": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@dev-plugins/react-navigation": "^0.0.6",
    "@stylistic/eslint-plugin": "^2.6.4",
    "@tanstack/eslint-plugin-query": "^5.53.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "babel-plugin-optional-require": "^0.3.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-expo": "^7.1.2",
    "jscodeshift": "0.15.2",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.5.0",
    "tsx": "^4.19.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

And my app.json:
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "test_mobile",
    "slug": "test-mobile",
    "scheme": "test-mobile",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "associatedDomains": [
        "applinks:test.com"
      ],
      "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.Test.mobile",
      "infoPlist": {
        "SKAdNetworkItems": [
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "xxxxx.skadnetwork"
          },
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "xxxxx.skadnetwork"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "autoVerify": true,
          "data": [
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.test.com",
              "pathPrefix": "/"
            }
          ],
          "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
        }
      ],
      "package": "com.anonymous.test_mobile",
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.INTERNET"
      ]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png",
      "output": "server"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin",
        {
          "iosUrlScheme": "xxxxx"
        }
      ],
      [
        "react-native-fbsdk-next",
        {
          "appID": "",
          "clientToken": "",
          "displayName": "Test",
          "isAutoInitEnabled": true
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "flipper": false
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-router",
        {
          "origin": ""
        }
      ],
      "expo-apple-authentication",
      "expo-secure-store"
    ],
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      },
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xxxxx"
      }
    },
    "owner": "me"
  }
}

This is solely an iOS/android app, so I'm not concerned with bundling for web necessarily. I do have a few web properties in the app.json (I think it's necessary to be able to use Expo server APIs for Stripe, etc?), so my feeling is that it's coming from there. The error doesn't give me too much information. How can I fix this error?
EDIT
After downgrading to expo@51.0.11 and expo-router@3.5.15, this is the error I'm seeing:
λ Bundling failed 186ms node_modules/expo-router/node/render.js (1 module)
Unable to resolve "react-dom/server.node" from "node_modules/expo-router/build/static/renderStaticContent.js"
Web node_modules/expo-router/entry.js ▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 22.1% ( 8/17)Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/jimmiejackson/Documents/repositories/gear_closet_mobile/node_modules/@expo/server/src/index.ts'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:603:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:471:35)
    at getCodeFrame (/Users/jimmiejackson/Documents/repositories/test_mobile/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:949:18)
    at Server._symbolicate (/Users/<me>/Documents/repositories/test_mobile/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1026:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Server._processRequest (/Users/<me>/Documents/repositories/test_mobile/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:419:7) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/<me>/Documents/repositories/test_mobile/node_modules/@expo/server/src/index.ts'
}

Metro error: Unable to resolve module react-dom/server.node from /Users/<me>/Documents/repositories/test_mobile/node_modules/expo-router/build/static/renderStaticContent.js: react-dom/server.node could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules/expo-router/node_modules
  node_modules
  ../../../node_modules
  38 | const Font = __importStar(require("expo-font/build/server"));
  39 | const react_1 = __importDefault(require("react"));
> 40 | const server_node_1 = __importDefault(require("react-dom/server.node"));
     |                                                ^
  41 | const react_native_web_1 = require("react-native-web");
  42 | const getRootComponent_1 = require("./getRootComponent");
  43 | const _ctx_1 = require("../../_ctx");


Call Stack
  metroFetchAsync (node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/getStaticRenderFunctions.ts:184:13)
  processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues)
  requireFileContentsWithMetro (node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/getStaticRenderFunctions.ts:163:10)
  getStaticRenderFunctionsForEntry (node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/getStaticRenderFunctions.ts:211:45)
  MetroBundlerDevServer.ssrLoadModule (node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.ts:404:7)
  bundleStaticHtml (node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.ts:360:36)
  MetroBundlerDevServer.getStaticPageAsync (node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.ts:373:52)
  getHtml (node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/metro/createServerRouteMiddleware.ts:73:31)
  handler (node_modules/@expo/server/src/index.ts:222:24)
Web Bundling failed 5947ms node_modules/expo-router/entry.js (2441 modules)
Unable to resolve "react-native-web/dist/index" from "node_modules/expo-router/build/renderRootComponent.js"


U might need to install the react-dom package using the following command

npm i react-dom


Why would I need to add react-dom if I'm not building for the web (iOS/android only)?

In my projects I do not build for web either but I have it installed as well. I think Expo still needs it.

Hello this issue is already posted in GitHub issue.
This problem related to expo-router.
Since there's no fix for current version, the current solution is to  downgrade expo to version 51.0.11 and expo-router to version 3.5.15

I'd actually come across that issue as well and didn't think it applied. I just tried downgrading to those versions mentioned, but now am getting a similar but slightly different error, which I've updated in the main post.

ow i see, after a quick research i found the most related problem with you check it out. Expo returns "Metro error: Unable to resolve module react-dom/server.node" error?
